# accepts_nested_attributes_for not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, nested-attributes

I have a work_order model and an odometer model.  I am trying to add an odometer reading for each work order, but also need to be able to add odometer readings without associating a work order to it.

I have the models setup like this:

```
#odometer.rb
class Odometer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :work_order
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :work_order
end

#work_order.rb
class WorkOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :odometer
end
```

I have the form setup like this:

```
    = form_for @work_order do |f|
      = f.label :created_at, "Start Date"
      = f.text_field :created_at, :class => "datepicker", :value => @work_order.created_at.nil? ? '' : @work_order.created_at.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
      %br
      = f.label :number, "Work Order #"
      = f.text_field :number
      %br 
      = f.label :complete_date, "Finish Date"
      = f.text_field :complete_date, :class => "datepicker", :value => @work_order.complete_date.nil? ? '' : @work_order.complete_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
      %br
      = f.label :mechanic_id
      = f.collection_select :mechanic_id, @mechanics, :id, :display_name

      = f.fields_for :odometer do |o|
        = o.label :mileage
        = o.number_field :mileage
      = f.label :equipment_id
      = f.collection_select :equipment_id, @all_equipment, :id, :name

      = f.label :description
      = readable_text_area f, :description, :style => "width:630px;height:100px;"

      = f.submit 'Save'
```

I can't seem to get this to save the odometer stuff.  I am sure I am doing something completely wrong, but I cant figure it out.

Thanks for any help.

Toby

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the form is a bit back to front. Going by the models the `Odometer` accepts nested attributes for `WorkOrder`. But the form is telling me it's the other way around.

Checkout this Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: I have watched that railscast many times hoping to not have to post this here.  I appreciate the link, and the advice.  Do you see another way to do that and have it work?  I am up for pretty much anything.  I just do not want to have a odometer_id in the work order model if I can help it.